# Is it possible to use input data to change object variables? Java

Tags: java, input, static, non-static

I've been attempting to use Scanner to ask for user inputs which will then be written to a object to save them.
However I've been running into conflicts with Static and Non Static Variables. My understanding of Static is that if I were to write my class as static it would prevent me from altering it, however I also cannot make my Main statement not be static.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Booking{
    public class Ticket{
        int Amount;     //To be used to record how many of a specific ticket are needed.
        int Price =6;
        public void SetAmount(int Order){
            this.Amount = Order;
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ticket Booking = new Ticket();
        System.out.println("How many tickets would you like?")
        int AmountBooked = scan.nextInt();
        Booking.SetAmount(AmountBooked);
    }
}
```

I'm fairly sure there are other errors in this code however over time I've tried to re run it with so many different parts commented out I am certain that the error is with the line 'Ticket Booking = new Ticket();' So I'd appreciate if that could be focused on.

Comment: `Scanner myScanner` and `scan.nextInt()` ? You should see how to use inner class.

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to use `Booking` as the name of a `Ticket` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make Booking `SetAmount` method `static`.or you need to crate object of class Booking method to do call method `SetAmount`.

like below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Booking{
    public  static   class Ticket{
        int Amount;     //To be used to record how many of a specific ticket are needed.
        int Price =6;
        public  void SetAmount(int Order){
            this.Amount = Order;
System.out.println("SetAmount="+Order);
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Booking.Ticket ticket=new Booking.Ticket();  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many tickets would you like?");
        int AmountBooked = scanner.nextInt();
        ticket.SetAmount(AmountBooked);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Booking.setAmout()` is trying to use the `Ticket` instance but the name is the same as the class. So this is more a problem of standardization there

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback, the static method doesn't seem to work as it is because it cannot be used with the variable 'this'. And I don't see precisely what you changed in the create object method however it also runs into the Static non Static error.

Comment: @J.Blake sorry for above answer . Now i have update my answer and its working fine.

Comment: You are a star, so I believe that using Booking.Ticket rather than just Ticket is to help the program find the class, however I'm afraid I don't understand how I am able to alter Static class variables.

Comment: just like we called method of Ticket class.

Answer (score 0):

Nested class can't be public, it needs to be private or default. And if you want to access it inside a static function (main in your case), it needs to be static. So, change

```
public class Ticket
       to
private static class Ticket
```

You're creating an object of Ticket class and naming it Booking. Booking is the name of your public class, so you can't reuse it to name your object, it will cause conflict. Rename your variable to some other identifier like "obj" or "ticket".

Also, replace

```
scan.nextInt();
   with
myScanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, try to keep in mind how your name some objects Scanner) and use those properly (close it when the app is done!)

add/override **toString** so you can get a human readable idea about the objects state

```
public class PWTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ticket booking = new Ticket();
        System.out.println("How many tickets would ...");
        int amountBooked = myScanner.nextInt();
        booking.setAmount(amountBooked);
        System.out.println(booking);
        myScanner.close();
    }
}

class Ticket {
    int amount;
    int price = 6;

    public void setAmount(int Order) {
        amount = Order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ticket [amount=" + amount + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }

}
```

and take a look to the name conventions [suggested by oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)